# The argument type 'Future<void> Function(String?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(NotificationResponse)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I'm trying to include local notifications in my Flutter project using the latest version flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0, and I have this error:

> The argument type 'Future Function(String?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(NotificationResponse)?

```
onDidReceiveNotificationResponse : onSelectNotification
```

This is my class:

```
class LocalNotificationService {
  LocalNotificationService();

  final _localNotificationService = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  final BehaviorSubject<String?> onNotificationClick = BehaviorSubject();

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_stat_android');

    DarwinInitializationSettings iosInitializationSettings =
    DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
    );

    final InitializationSettings settings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings,
      iOS: iosInitializationSettings,
    );

    await _localNotificationService.initialize(
      settings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse : onSelectNotification, //here is the error
    );
  }

  Future<NotificationDetails> _notificationDetails() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('channel_id', 'channel_name',
            channelDescription: 'description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max,
            playSound: true);

    const DarwinNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails =
    DarwinNotificationDetails();

    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: iosNotificationDetails,
    );
  }

  Future<void> showNotification({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String body,
  }) async {
    final details = await _notificationDetails();
    await _localNotificationService.show(id, title, body, details);
  }

  Future<void> showScheduledNotification(
      {required int id,
      required String title,
      required String body,
      required int seconds}) async {
    final details = await _notificationDetails();
    await _localNotificationService.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      tz.TZDateTime.from(
        DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: seconds)),
        tz.local,
      ),
      details,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }

  Future<void> showNotificationWithPayload(
      {required int id,
      required String title,
      required String body,
      required String payload}) async {
    final details = await _notificationDetails();
    await _localNotificationService.show(id, title, body, details,
        payload: payload);
  }

  void onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) {
    print('id $id');
  }

  Future<void> onSelectNotification(String? payload) async {
    print('payload $payload');
    if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {
      onNotificationClick.add(payload);
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` provide `NotificationResponse` on callback.  You can get `payload` like

```dart
  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) =>
      onSelectNotification(details.payload),
```

Or

```dart
  Future<void> onSelectNotification(NotificationResponse? response) async {
    print('payload $response');
    if (response?.payload != null && response!.payload!.isNotEmpty) {
      onNotificationClick.add(response.payload);
    }
  }
```

And this will be used  `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse : onSelectNotification`.

Comment: Glad to help, more about [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin-class.html)